# How to handle errors from parallel web requests using Retrofit + RxJava?

Tags: retrofit2, rx-java2

I have a situation like this where I make some web requests in parallel. Sometimes I make these calls and all requests see the same error (e.g. no-network):

```
void main() {
    Observable.just("a", "b", "c")
            .flatMap(s -> makeNetworkRequest())
            .subscribe(
                    s -> {
                        // TODO
                    },
                    error -> {
                        // handle error
                    });
}

Observable<String> makeNetworkRequest() {
    return Observable.error(new NoNetworkException());
}

class NoNetworkException extends Exception {
}
```

Depending on the timing, if **one** request emits the `NoNetworkException` before the others can, Retrofit/RxJava will dispose/interrupt** the others. I'll see one of the following logs (not all three) for each request remaining in progress++:

```
<-- HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: Canceled
<-- HTTP FAILED: java.io.InterruptedIOException
<-- HTTP FAILED: java.io.InterruptedIOException: thread interrupted
```

I'll be able to handle the NoNetworkException error in the subscriber and everything downstream will get disposed of and all is OK.

However based on timing, if **two or more** web requests emit `NoNetworkException`, then the first one will trigger the events above, disposing of everything down stream. The second `NoNetworkException` will have nowhere to go and I'll get the dreaded `UndeliverableException`. This is the same as example #1 documented [here](https://medium.com/@bherbst/the-rxjava2-default-error-handler-e50e0cab6f9f).

In the above article, the author suggested using an error handler. Obviously `retry`/`retryWhen` don't make sense if I expect to hear the same errors again. I don't understand how `onErrorResumeNext`/`onErrorReturn` help here, unless I map them to something recoverable to be handled downstream:

```
Observable.just("a", "b", "c")
        .flatMap(s ->
                makeNetworkRequest()
                        .onErrorReturn(error -> {
                            // eat actual error and return something else
                            return "recoverable error";
                        }))
        .subscribe(
                s -> {
                    if (s.equals("recoverable error")) {
                        // handle error
                    } else {
                        // TODO
                    }
                },
                error -> {
                    // handle error
                });
```

but this seems wonky.

I know another solution is to set a global error handler with `RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler()`. This doesn't seem like a great solution either. I may want to handle `NoNetworkException` differently in different parts of my app.

So what other options to I have? What do other people do in this case? This must be pretty common.

** I don't fully understand who is interrupting/disposing of who. Is RxJava disposing of all other requests in flatmap which in turn causes Retrofit to cancel requests? Or does Retrofit cancel requests, resulting in each
request in flatmap emitting one of the above IOExceptions? I guess it doesn't really matter to answer the question, just curious.

++ It's possible that not all a, b, and c requests are in flight depending on thread pool.

Comment: Have you actually experienced this? In the given examples from the medium post, all operators can run their observables in parallel, which would lead to the situation described. However, in your example you have a flatmap. I'm struggling to understand how can both observables fail. As far as I know, flatmap requires the first observable to finish in order to run the next one. In other words, if one errors the other shouldn't run at all. Did I miss something?

Comment: I think you are thinking of `concatmap` which will run the inner Observables "serially"

Comment: Not really, I mean at least with your example I find it odd you managed to get this behavior. That's why I was asking if you're definitely sure you're experiencing the same problem. I have several cases like yours in the app I work with and never came across this issue, that's why I was intrigued.

Comment: ok, for me the error doesn't happen all the time. depending on random timing it's possible that the first request fails before the second one fires off, but it *is* possible that two requests are in flight at the same time.

Comment: oh I see now. You mean there are several `flatmap` triggers before one has finished? In other words, `makeNetworkRequest` triggers several times for each string emitted by `just` and sometimes one is still running while the others start?

Comment: The way I understand it, for each `just` emission, there will be one `makeNetworkRequest()#1`, but that won't block `just` to emit another one, which will trigger `makeNetworkRequest()#2`, and so forth. The problem is that the error consumer is not able to consume a potential error in make network request #1 *and* #2 because the 1st one will end the stream in error. Unless I misread… :p

Comment: Have you tried by using `flatMap()` with `delayErrors=true`?

Comment: @ctranxuan Nice! You should make this an answer so I can mark it as the right answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried by using flatMap() with delayErrors=true?